# I can not access my db

Tags: asp.net

I make a software in C# .net express edition  in  in windows 7.But When I run this software in other machine in which install windows XP,it can not run due to instance failure.When I set the break point in other machine code,I see that it hold the database location path of my machine.Actually i want to access the db from my debug folder.
Like..

- DB Location in may machine -- F:\MY Project\Tracking Soft\bin\debug\TRack.mdf
- DB Location In Other Machine -- E:\Tracking Soft\bin\debug\TRack.mdf

I mean that in the both machine the connection string is same but the project location is different

Comment: Can you go into a bit more detail? It's very unclear from your question how anyone here would be able to help you.

Comment: Actually.In the both machine connection string is ..Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=F:\Delivered && Updated 30.12.2013\BP_Tracking Soft\CA TRACKING\CATracking\CATracking\bin\Debug\bpTracking.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True

But The project location in the both machine is different .

Answer (score 0):

When using SQL Server express, you can put your database file into the App_Data folder (e.g. in CATracking\App_Data). Then you should be able to access it using a connection string like this one:

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|TRack.mdf;Database=...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
private string dbPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\bpTracking.mdf";
```

But your bpTracking.mdf isn't in the correct directory. Move it into \bin\Debug for this code to work.